# A question about integer quantization during the forward pass

Tags: neural-networks, graph-neural-network

I am reading the a paper by Tailor, Fernandez-Marques, and Lane called [Degree-quant: quantization-aware training
for graph neural networks](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=NSBrFgJAHg). In the paper, it is written:

> For integer QAT [quantization-aware training], the quantization of a tensor $x$ during the forward pass is often implemented as:
> $$x_q = \min\left(q_{\max}, \max\left(q_{\min}, \lfloor x/s+z \rfloor \right) \right)$$
> where $q_{\min}$ and $q_{\max}$ are the minimum and maximum representable values at a given bit-width and signedness $s$ is the scaling factor making $x$ span the $[q_{\min}, q_{\max}]$ range, and $z$ is the zero-point, which allows for the real value 0 to be representable in $x_q$.

Can someone please explain what the formula does? I mean a detailed explanation about the variables that are explained in the *where* part after the formula. I am new to the field so any related reference suggestion is also appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you do and don't understand about those values? How much do you already understand about number representation in computers, e.g. fixed- or floating-point?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thank you for your comment. I am familiar with floating points, integers, etc. Also, when it says minimum and maximum representable values, if we consider unsigned 8-bits then min=0 and max=255, while with an 8-bit signed integer, min= -128 and max=127, both representing 256 distinct numbers. But what are those signedness _s_ as the scaling factor and _z_? I think if there was an example of a tensor _x_ to which the formula was applied, I could understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a trivial algebra. you're chopping the continuous variable into a few chunks, which can be represented by integer numbers. It's a combination of three tricks: a) linear spline (min/max functions), b) scale and shift ($s$ and $z$) and c) discretization (floor function).

For instance, if you set $z=-10$ and $s=5$, then $x\in[50,55)$ would be represented by $x_q=0$. It's not much different from a standard scaling where for $s$ you use the standard deviation and $z$ is the mean. Here, $q_{min},q_{max}$ are simply the bounds of a discretized variable $x_q$

The trick with min and max functions is quite popular when you want to collar the variable between min and max value. It creates S-letter like shape of the resulting variable. It's used in [linear splines](https://datacadamia.com/data_mining/linear_spline) in data science. For instance, when you want to have changing slopes in different sections of the regressors.

Comment: What are the criteria of choosing z and s, in other words, how do I choose them? And did you consider 8-bit quantisation in your answer?

Comment: 8 bit is really just a matter of how many chunks you want to have, e.g. 256 in the case of 8 bit. For instance, the following $s,z,x_{min},x_{max}$ values: 5,-10,0,255 will map the interval [50,1330) to an unsigned 8 bit integer. The choice of parameters is specific to your problem. There's no general rule.

Comment: a signed 8-bit integer's domain is [-128,127], so with values of the same parameters 5,-10,-128,127 you map an interval [-590,690] to a signed 8-bit integer. this data type is often called a byte

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer and explanation.